# Two MessageBox quit confirmation messages

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my confirmation messages..
I have two MessageBox, the first one ask "Do you want to quit?"
The second one, ask "Are you sure!?"
My problem is that if I choose yes when the first MessageBox "Do you want to quit?" show up, the second MessageBox will still appear..

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            var confirmationBox = MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to quit", @"Title",
                                                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            var confirmationBox2 = MessageBox.Show(@"Are you sure?", @"", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);


            if (confirmationBox == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (confirmationBox2 == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but just so you know, it is not common practice to place `@`s before string literals unless there is a reason to (e.g. the string contains backslashes or line breaks).

Comment: This is the way you have it coded of course it's going to show up..look at your code.. also debug the code I tried it and it's working the way it should perhaps you need to place the second one inside of the conditional statement

Comment: You're right, I'm still a beginner.. We learn from our mistakes. lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't show the second message box until you have inspected the results of the first:

```
var confirmationBox = MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to quit", @"Title",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (confirmationBox == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    var confirmationBox2 = MessageBox.Show(@"Are you sure?", @"", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (confirmationBox2 == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

P.S. annoying your users with dialogs such as these are annoying; consider not doing this unless there's a real compelling reason that they shouldn't close right now (i.e. in the middle of an operation that would be left in an invalid state, or have unsaved data).

Comment: @JohnBaughman Seconds?  According to the timestamp I posted my answer 10 minutes before you...

Comment: @Servy Semantics... ;-) Yeah, my browser did some weird stuff for a moment or two...

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is you are showing the message boxes then checking each response.

What you want to do is within your if statements is do the show and check for the response.

```
if (MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to quit", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes) {
    if (MessageBox.Show(@"Are you sure?", @"", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No) {
       e.Cancel = true; 
    }
}
```